# Where and how should authority checks in a WebDynpro application happen in order to enable or disable controls?

Tags: abap, webdynpro

There are several screens in Web Dynpro, on which certain fields and buttons, which, depending on whether the user has an object of authority, should be active or inactive.

I have an authority object with the `ACTVT` field. Various actions are prescribed there ("Change", "Delete", "Create", etc.) For example, there is an "Edit" button on the screen. For users who have this permission object, this button is active, for those who do not have this object, the button is not active. When a user enters this screen, as I understand it, there should be a check - whether he has this authority object or not. And now I don't quite understand where this check should be carried out

So far, I know very little about Web Dynpro technology. I studied documentation, small courses and searched for everything that is on the Internet. I do not understand where it is better to start and where exactly to implement the `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT` check.

Comment: Its not clear to me exactly what the issue is.  WHat you are trying to control.
Which web dynpro apps do you refer to ?
Are you referring to the personalization / configuration of fields for Web dynpro apps.?
Perhaps this topic https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/fc79a39b30fe4d9aa983bad6787ab9ad/f6edad448a55462d85fbb5ce2dfa84a8.html

Comment: Updated the problem description

Comment: I can't cite SAP's practice recommendation in this regard, but the dominant SAP approach is to have dedicated display and change applications. Therefore, controlling feature visibility in a universal app represents a novel approach to a common problem and will make system maintenance harder, so it should be avoided.